# Could not login to Facebook after February 6 changes

Tags: facebook, windows-8

After "February 6 changes" my app could not login to Facebook. We enabled "February 2013 Breaking Changes" one week ago. But app still not work.

We use C# and `WebAuthenticationBroker` for OAUTH connect. I tried to create new FB app but problem is same: "We can`t connect to the service you need right now. Check your network connection or try this again later".

I noticed that if I try execute request in webbrowser I get redirect to https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html without typing any private data.

Redirecting Link: https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=AAAEoZAxJSugQBAFSbqnZCmjqKVAw3oTMKaD1ZBq3RNAPNBEdyE0ntJILqjIcEmZA4H1zaPdj8C9RZA3XWKcv6xFtj9TdV4fVilKUMhDPCI0BUUtEf5MvY&expires_in=5650

Page content:

> Success

Maybe was some changes in format of uri, because EndUri is correct. But WebAuthenticationBroker can not parse access_token. Maybe previously in URI was used symbols '?' instead of '#' ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to change your solution, but perhaps what you would like to use is the Windows Azure Mobile Services Facebook Authentication API. This will handle all the messy oauth for you and, as a bonus, give you Google, Twitter, and Windows Live authentication, too. And it supports C# (like you), but also JavaScript, WinRT, and even objective C. Depending on how you use it, it's free.

Watch: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services/Windows-Store-app-Getting-Started-with-Authentication-in-Windows-Azure-Mobile-Services

Read: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-users-dotnet/

Comment: Thanks for links. Unfortunately, this is not a solution in my case. I need to get access_token and send it to my own service. Adding additional Azure service is redundant in my case. 

Moreover, WebAuthenticationBroker did his job well. WebAuthenticationBroker allows you to connect to any Oauth 2.0 service. 

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122